# FatalExecutionEngineError in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, exception, richtextbox, fatal-error

Sometimes, just sometime, I get **FatalExecutionEngineError** while trying to get text position from mouse position in RichTextBox. And the second problem is I can't handle **FatalExecutionEngineError** and it crashes the app.

```
// e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(XAMLRichBox) is not null
var tp = myRichBox.GetPositionFromPoint(e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(XAMLRichBox), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the similar problem when working with RichTextFormat and probably my experience may help you too.

I've encountered the abovementioned exception when user was calling Undo action in richtextedit control. The exception was thrown on undo if there are particular actions has been done previously that included the insert into CaretPosition the content of the separately created FlowDocument:

```
Document.ContentStart.InsertParagraphBreak();
RichTextBox.InsertDocument(Document, RichTextBox.CaretPosition);
```

My solution was to envelope the above action in BeginChange()/EndChange() (that was perfectly suited the requirements):

```
RichTextBox.BeginChange();
try
{
    Document.ContentStart.InsertParagraphBreak();
    RichTextBox.InsertDocument(Document, RichTextBox.CaretPosition); 
}
finally
{
    RichTextBox.EndChange();
}
```

I guess this might give you idea to solve your problem